# How to Read and Add Rules in Windows Firewall with Python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm creating a service that needs to constantly monitor the Firewall to prevent unsuspecting users from removing the doors of a service. My intention is to do this using python.

So, I searched for it and did not think.

can I read and add rules to Windows Firewall using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Python IDLE as an administrator or CMD as administrator and load python. Aim is so that while running the program you should have administrator privilege.

```
def blockrule():
 import os
 c=input('Enter Directory in the format "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\"(without ""): \n')
 d=input('Enter prefix: ')
 e=input('Enter \n"1" for inbound \n"2" for outbound \n"3" for both \nWithout ""\n')
 a=[];b=[]
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(c):
  for name in files:
   a=a+[[(os.path.join(root,name))]]
 for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i][0][-3:]=='exe':
   b=b+a[i]
 print('Number of files: '+str(len(a))+'\nNumber of .exe files: '+str(len(b)))
 for i in range (len(b)):
  name=d+str(i)
  if e=='1':
   os.popen('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="'+name+'" dir=in action=block program= "'+ b[i]+'" enable=yes profile=any')
  if e=='2':
   os.popen('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="'+name+'" dir=out action=block program= "'+ b[i]+'" enable=yes profile=any')
  if e=='3':
   os.popen('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="'+name+'" dir=in action=block program= "'+ b[i]+'" enable=yes profile=any')
   os.popen('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="'+name+'" dir=out action=block program= "'+ b[i]+'" enable=yes profile=any')
```

Comment: When adding source code to your post please use the required decorations in order to mark text as code and also in order to separate paragraph into code lines. Please read 'Markdown help' to get full specifications. Also please write exactly what your code aiming to do.